# Java RSA signature mechanism equivalent to emsa-pkcs1-v1_5 with SHA-256

Tags: java, rsa, sign, sha, pkcs#1

I need to sign data using Java with the `SHA-256` and `EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5` encoding and RSA private key.

Also I need to use padding type 1 in `EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5` which means that the data before signing should be appended by zeros (not random data, as in padding type 2).

The output of the signature on the same data should be the same.

What is equivalent in Java to this mechanism?

I was trying to sign using `SHA256withRSA` but the output on the same data is always different.

**EDIT:**

I am using the following code (data, sigAlg, and cert is always the same, so I assume that the signature should be always the same):

```
CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator();
String sigAlg = "SHA256withRSA";
ContentSigner contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(sigAlg).setProvider("BC").build(getPrivateKey());
generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(contentSigner, cert));
generator.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(certs));
OutputStream out = generator.open(responseOutputStream);
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

Comment: " I was trying to sign using SHA256withRSA."  Show some code. I assume you're using the [Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class?

Comment: See the post, there is a sample of code for CMS signed data where I am using `SHA256withRSA`. The result is always different and it should be the same.